# Changing font-family of Google Maps API

Tags: css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I can't find any up to date information about whether or not this is possible. I know the documentation itself makes no mention of changing the font for anything other than marker labels. Is this possible? If so, how?!

Answer (score -1):

Yes, It,s possible, You can change the `font-family` of Google Maps API.

For example, To change `font-family`'s tooltip  marker, use this selector:

```
.gm-style-iw div div
```

Inspect Map and find selector to change font-family.

Comment: @Yosi Sheetrit @Morteza QorbanAlizade soooo i've determined that it's the `document.getElementById('google-map-container').childNodes[0].childNodes[2]` that sets the `font-family` of the map, but for some reason the font that I set will not be displayed **even though** the console is logging the new font as the `font-family`'s value...?